# Change header Infos binary and write it back

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, file, arrays

I need to change the header informations of a file in document folder. 
What is the most recommended way to read and write back binary data?

1. How to read the data from document folder binary to array / stream
2. How to write the data back from array / stream to local iPad document folder?

[image: Binary reading / writing in objective-c]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one is hard to answer without you being a little more specific, but the most efficient way to do this would arguably be to **not change the file at all.**

Since we’re talking about iOS, there is no file-system-level access to those documents apart from your application itself. So why not save the additional/customized header data that you want to associate with your files in an application-wide meta-data-store (like e.g. iTunes or iPhoto do) and interleave them with the *actual* file headers during exports only?

Regardless of that, I don’t really see a compelling reason to drop down to the C-level file functions to change those data: `NSInputStream` provides you with streaming file reading-access and `NSOutputStream` can be used to stream data to a file.

If you go with my suggestion from above you’d likely end up with an API like this:

```
typedef void (^DataExportHandler)(NSData *resultData, NSError *exportError);

@interface DataStore (FileExport)

/** If you wanted to abort the export, you could pass the stream into the `abort…:`-method
@param  identifier  Something that you use internally to manage your stored files.
@param  error       For good measure…
@return The export stream for the object or `nil` if an error occurred.
*/
- (NSInputStream *)exportStreamForObjectWithIdentifier:(id)identifier error:(NSError * __autoreleasing*)error;

/** If your data are mostly small, it may be more convenient to not consume the exports as streams but as BLOBs, if the sizes vary you could implement this as a convenience…
@param  identifier  Equivalent to the identifier in the method above
@param  handler     Callback that is invoked once some time later when the export finished or failed. **Must not** be `nil`.
*/
@return A cancellation token.
- (id)asynchronouslyExportDataForObjectWithIdentifier:(id)identifier resultHandler:(DataExportHandler)handler;

/**
@param  exportToken  Either a stream from the first method or a token returned from the second one.
*/
- (void)abortAsynchronousExportWithToken:(id)exportToken;

@end
```

Assuming ARC and not knowing what you have to do to interleave the additional metadata with the original, here is what the boilerplate part of the implementation *might* look like.

The beef would clearly be in the part that I don’t show here: implementation of the delegate for the `rawDataStream` where you’d consume the data from the original file, interleaving the headers with your additional information.
Although this should probably be factored out into a separate class, I’ve just implied that the data-store implements the `NSStreamDelegate` callbacks accordingly.

After the headers you’d just pass through the rest of the file…

```
/// Scribble of another helper class that can be used whenever one needs to consume a stream for its aggregate data:
@interface _StreamConsumer : NSObject <NSStreamDelegate> {
    NSInputStream *_stream;
    DataExportHandler _handler;
    NSMutableData *_data;
}

// initiate the data, set itself as the stream’s delegate, open and schedule the stream in a runloop.
- (id)initWithInputStream:(NSInputStream *)stream resultHandler:(DataExportHandler)handler;

// forward the close to the stream
- (void)close;

// Implementation of the stream delegate callbacks can be more or less copy-pasted from Apple’s Stream Programming Guide (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Streams.html)
@end

@implementation DataStore (FileExport)

- (id)asynchronouslyExportDataForObjectWithIdentifier:(id)someUniqueIdentifier resultHandler:(void (^)(NSData *fileData, NSError *exportError))
{
    NSParameterAssert(handler);
    handler = [handler copy];

    NSError *setupError;
    NSInputStream *exportStream = [self exportStreamForObjectWithIdentifier:someUniqueIdentifier error:&setupError];
    if (!exportStream)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^{
            handler(nil, setupError);
        });

        return nil;
    }

    _StreamConsumer *helper = [[_StreamConsumer alloc] initWithStream:exportStream resultHandler:handler];

    return helper;
}

- (void)abortAsynchronousExportWithToken:(id)exportToken
{
    [exportToken close];
}

- (NSInputStream *)exportStreamForObjectWithIdentifier:(id)identifier error:(NSError * __autoreleasing*)error
{
    // do your thing to retrieve the URL to the actual data-file and then:
    NSInputStream *rawDataStream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithURL:rawFileURL];

    if (!rawDataStream)
    {
        // populate the error in a meaningful way
        return nil;
    }

    CFReadStream cfExportStream;
    CFWriteStream cfBuffer;
    CFStreamCreateBoundPair(kCFAllocatorDefault, &cfExportStream, &cfBuffer, someValueYouHaveTuned);

    if (!cfExportStream || !cfBuffer)
    {
        // error population
        return nil;
    }

    NSInputStream *exportStream = (__bridge_transfer NSInputStream *)cfExportStream;

    // HACKITY HACK: In reality, you’d want this stuff separated!
    // For the sake of simplicity, take the responsibility for that ourselves
    _exportBuffer = (__bridge_transfer NSOutputStream *)cfBuffer;

    rawDataStream.delegate = self;
    [rawDataStream open];
    [rawDataStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSRunloopDefaultMode];
    // END: HACKITY HACK

    return exportStream;
}

@end
```

Comment: hi. thanks for the answer. perhaps you can show where to write the sample with a start index read of byte with 11? Until reading to byte index 255?

Answer (score 3):

Main bundle is readonly you can't write there anything. 
For writing we have document directory.
This will read file from the main bundle

```
NSString *path= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myFile" ofType:@"txt"];
```

---

**Edited** 
As you have shown your header is from 1 to 10 byte..
Could you tell me one think how one who is reading your file knows that what is the exact length of your header. It can be 2, 3 or 7 anything between 1 to 10. There must be a way to tell that it has header of specific length and same is the case with the other part of the file. 
Without this info I don't think that one will ever know the size of your header, body or footer. 
If I have created this file I might have put first byte of the header as length of header so that any one can read header and after reading the header the first byte after that have made for size of body and same for the footer.

Comment: thanks. That answers a part of the question. Are you able to give any answer to the both questions regarding reading/writing fragments of file?

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer. But the most secret is still not clear which is how to split the file in 3 parts.

Answer (score 1):

C streams are easy enough: `FILE*`, `fopen`, `fseeko`, `fread`, `fwrite`.

if your data's just 266 bytes, that's small enough that you can just read it all in using `[NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]` and then write it back out (overwriting the entire file) using `NSData`'s `write*` methods. however, you will want to avoid this approach with larger files. at that point, you will want to use C interfaces (above), or consider `NSFileHandle`, `NSInputStream`, `NSOutputStream`, `CFReadStream`, `CFWriteStream`, etc..